# How to tint the active resp. selected image of a tab bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uikit

I have got a tab bar driven app. And I managed to tint nearly all the UI elements that I am aiming to.

There is just one thing. The tab bar has titles and icons (png images, assigned named in storyboard/IB). Both is tinted nicely when I tint the tab bar as follows:

```
// Tab Bar
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabController.tabBar.tintColor = self.colorTabBar;
```

Currently I am using some greenish theme. But the very one tab bar icon that is highlighted, the one of the tab that is active, is nice and shiny but blueish. And this blueish tint simply doest not agree with the other colors.

I am storyboarding the app, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`selectedImageTintColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/selectedImageTintColor) property on `UITabBar`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I overlooked this one because my local copy of the class reference was outdated. It's about time to update the lot of them.